# Intent.getSerializableExtra(obj) returns null in onReceive of BroadcastReceiver when setting up Alarm

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to start an alarm and pass an object to the intent that will be received by the BroadcastReceiver subclass firing the alarm but no matter what I pass to the Intent, it will not be save and the Intent received will be null

**Here is my code :**

(Setting up alarm):

```
        private void startAlarm() {
           Girafe girafe = new Girafe("holly");
           int hash = 1
           // set the date of the alarm to be in one minute
           Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
           c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1); 

           // Create the alarm
           AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);

           // I pass here the object I want to be received on alarm fired
           intent.putExtra("myObject", girafe);
           intent.putExtra("myStr", "hello");
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, hash, intent, 0);
           alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        }
```

(Receiving and firing the alarm):

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       String myStr = intent.getStringExtra("myStr") // I receive something null here
       Girage g = (Girafe) intent.getSerializableExtra("myObject"); // same here

    }
```

Where is the problem here ?

PS : I know this problem has been raised 7 month ago here [Intent getting null in onReceive in MyAlarm class even though I sat putExtra while sending intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626182/intent-getting-null-in-onreceive-in-myalarm-class-even-though-i-sat-putextra-whi) but no one solved it.

Comment: What is `hash`?

Comment: `it will not be save and the Intent received will be null` No. The intent is not null. but `intent.getStringExtra("myStr")` will return null. If not then be clear.

Comment: Try without putting the girafe.

Comment: I replaced hash by 1 (simple request code). Indeed, intent.getStringExtra("myStr") returns null

Comment: Well then change your subject and the text in our post.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work. If you pass a custom object (ie: one that Android doesn't know about), the `AlarmManager` isn't able to deserialize the object and it is ignored. That is why you don't ever see the object in the "extras" when the alarm is triggered.

To get around this you can serialize your object into a `byte` array or a `String` and put that in the "extras". `AlarmManager` knows about `byte` arrays and `String`s so you should see the serialized object in the "extras" when the alarm triggers. Then you will need to deserialize the `byte` array or `String` and recreate the object yourself.

Another potential problem is that you do this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, hash, intent, 0);
```

This call does not always **create** a new `PendingIntent`. It may return an **existing** `PendingIntent` which does NOT have your "extras" in it. To ensure that this doesn't happen, you should do this:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, hash, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Adding `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` will ensure that your "extras" are copied into the `PendingIntent`, even if an existing one is being returned.